# Submit forms data in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I have components where In each I have one form on click of next I am opening a new form( calling new component) and when it is last I am changing it to submit.

**What I want to achieve**

1: on each next and back click I want to validate my form using react-form-hook

2: on click of submit I should able to see all the data

3: while clicking on next to back data should not loss from inputs

**Issue**

So for validation I am using [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) as it is very simple to use, but here I am not able to find out as my buttons are not inside the forms they are in main component so How will I validate and on submit the form on submit click wit all data.

**My code**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Form1 from "./components/Form1";
import Form2 from "./components/Form2";
import Form3 from "./components/Form3";

function AddCompanyMain() {
  const [currState, setCurrState] = useState(1);
  const [allState, setAllstate] = useState(3);

  const moveToPrevious = () => {
    setCurrState(currState - 1);
  };
  const moveToNext = () => {
    setCurrState(currState + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div class="progress">
        <div>{currState}</div>
      </div>

      {currState === 1 && <Form1 />}
      {currState === 2 && <Form2 />}
      {currState === 3 && <Form3 />}

      {currState !== 1 && (
        <button
          className="btn btn-primary"
          type="button"
          onClick={moveToPrevious}
        >
          back
        </button>
      )}
      {currState !== allState && (
        <button className="btn btn-primary" type="button" onClick={moveToNext}>
          next
        </button>
      )}

      {currState === 3 && (
        <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddCompanyMain;
```

My Full code [Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-engelbart-oisdv?file=/src/components/Form2.js)

I am just looking for a good approach because here I can't put submit in each component, because I have to show steps at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can solve your problem by doing the following:**

- In app.js, store the forms in an array of objects and render them based on the step(currentFrom state).
- Call `useForm` in parent component (not in child Form component) and pass `register, errors, defaultValues` values as props to your `Form` components.
- In your `Form` components, you need to grab `register, etc` as props
- Maintain `defaultValues` in a state and update them in the `onClick` of next/previous. You need to [getValues](https://react-hook-form.com/api#getValues) and then use [setValues](https://react-hook-form.com/api#setValue) to set the state(defaultValues)

**Also:**

- In order to trigger validation on next/previous button click, you need to use [triggerValidation](https://react-hook-form.com/api#triggerValidation)
- In order to retain values when you click next/previous, you need to use [defaultValues](https://react-hook-form.com/api#useForm) prop

See the [working demo is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-form-hook-issue-fix-bbz5t?file=/src/App.js)

**Code Snippet**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Form1 from "./components/Form1";
import Form2 from "./components/Form2";
import Form3 from "./components/Form3";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

function AddCompanyMain() {
  const {
    register,
    triggerValidation,
    errors,
    setValue,
    getValues
  } = useForm();
  const [defaultValues, setDefaultValues] = useState({});

  const forms = [
    {
      fields: ["uname"],
      component: (register, errors, defaultValues) => (
        <Form1
          register={register}
          errors={errors}
          defaultValues={defaultValues}
        />
      )
    },
    {
      fields: ["lname"],
      component: (register, errors, defaultValues) => (
        <Form2
          register={register}
          errors={errors}
          defaultValues={defaultValues}
        />
      )
    },
    {
      fields: ["company"],
      component: (register, errors, defaultValues) => (
        <Form3
          register={register}
          errors={errors}
          defaultValues={defaultValues}
        />
      )
    }
  ];

  const [currentForm, setCurrentForm] = useState(0);

  const moveToPrevious = () => {
    setDefaultValues(prev => ({ ...prev, [currentForm]: getValues() }));

    triggerValidation(forms[currentForm].fields).then(valid => {
      if (valid) setCurrentForm(currentForm - 1);
    });
  };

  const moveToNext = () => {
    console.log(getValues());
    setDefaultValues(prev => ({ ...prev, [currentForm]: getValues() }));
    triggerValidation(forms[currentForm].fields).then(valid => {
      if (valid) setCurrentForm(currentForm + 1);
    });
  };

  const prevButton = currentForm !== 0;
  const nextButton = currentForm !== forms.length - 1;

  return (
    <div>
      <div class="progress">
        <div>{currentForm}</div>
      </div>

      {forms[currentForm].component(
        register,
        errors,
        defaultValues[currentForm]
      )}

      {prevButton && (
        <button
          className="btn btn-primary"
          type="button"
          onClick={moveToPrevious}
        >
          back
        </button>
      )}
      {nextButton && (
        <button className="btn btn-primary" type="button" onClick={moveToNext}>
          next
        </button>
      )}

      {currentForm === 3 && (
        <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddCompanyMain;
```

Note - In general, when working with multi step forms, it is better to use controlled components and maintain the states in the parent component

Comment: Hey your solution is fine if each form has one one input field here in my case I have multiple input fields in each form, suppose for example I have 2 input in my form one and i.e is age so in main components in field array I am passing the second value i.e age so it is working fine but when I come back i.e from from 2 to 1 the values both input fields are taking is same i.e what ever i am passing in u name the age is taking the same.

Comment: umm... give me the codesandbox where u've put the age, i'll fix it

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-glade-ei1in?file=/src/App.js  Hey here is my code sandbox, age I have just taken for example the main point is forms can have multiple fields none of the form is going to have one field.

Comment: just checked - in your example, uname & age are taking same values because you have set the age input `defaultValue` incorrectly. i.e. you have used defaultValues.uname instead of `.age`. So for age input do `defaultValue={defaultValues && defaultValues.age}` ... hope its all good now...

Comment: Hey I didn't get your solution could you please share the `codesandbox` link.

Comment: here https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-fire-8xsz0   ... basically, in `Form1` component, in line 25, do `defaultValues.age` instead of defaults.uname

Comment: hey on submit I want all my forms data like uname:"test", age:"22" ... now where should I do `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>` to handel the submit

Comment: `defaultValues` will have all your form data ..... so have an onClick on Submit button in `App.js` and simply get it from state... i have updated the code ... refresh the same sandbox link ...

Comment: its simple ... use `{ ...defaultValues, [currentForm]: getValues() }` in handleSubmit, you will get entire form data ... i have updated the code in sandbox .. use the same link

Comment: Hey could you please help me out with some approach on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63814645/how-to-create-dynamic-elements-inside-global-tabs  I ahve been stuck here for long now

Answer (score 1):

You can [lift the value state of each component up to the parent](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), and then pass an onChange prop to each to update the state from each child. I'm not sure how this will play with react-hooks-form, but this is generally how you want to synchronize states of child components.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const FormOne = ({ value, onChange }) => (
  <div>
    Form 1
    <input type='text' value={value} onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)} />
  </div>

)

const FormTwo = ({ value, onChange }) => (
  <div>
    Form 2
    <input type='text' value={value} onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)} />
  </div>
)

const FormThree = ({ value, onChange }) => (
  <div>
    Form 3
    <input type='text' value={value} onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)} />
  </div>
)

export default function App() {
  const [formOne, setFormOne] = React.useState('')
  const [formTwo, setFormTwo] = React.useState('')
  const [formThree, setFormThree] = React.useState('')
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0)

  const moveUp = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    if (index !== 2) {
      setIndex(index => index += 1)
    }
  }

  const moveDown = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    if (index !== 0) {
      setIndex(index => index -= 1)
    }
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    console.log(formOne, formTwo, formThree)
  }

  const form = index === 0
    ? <FormOne value={formOne} onChange={setFormOne} />
    : index === 1
    ? <FormTwo value={formTwo} onChange={setFormTwo} />
    : <FormThree value={formThree} onChange={setFormThree} />

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        {form}
        {index !== 0 && <button onClick={moveDown}>Back</button>}
        {index !== 2
          ? <button onClick={moveUp}>Next</button>
          : <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        }
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Check the edit. Lots of optimizations to be made here, but this should get you started.